Why has FiveThirtyEight stopped updating the presidential election polling average?
I’ve been using FiveThirtyEight presidential election polling averages to keep track of the election predictions. However, since Joe Biden dropped out they have stopped updating the polling average. I can’t see any explanation why - can’t they simply keep posting the averages while adding the presumptive Democratic candidate Kamala Harris?
My question is thus: has FiveThirtyEight explained this somewhere, and if not, what may be the explanation?

I haven't seen anything either, but it may have been mentioned on one of the podcast episodes I haven't listened to yet.  That said, Nate Silver (no longer with 538) released his Trump/Harris model yesterday: https://www.natesilver.net/p/nate-silver-2024-president-election-polls-model, although most of the details beyond the topline results are behind the paywall.

@Bobson thanks, I guess 538 just lost a customer

"I can’t see any explanation why..." Maybe they don't trust their own results anymore. After all, the situation is a bit unusual.

538 is a shadow of its former self.  There's no real lead, nobody to make a decision on how to handle the change of nominee.  Perhaps it also would require someone to change some of the software. 538 was essentially de-funded by ABC and exists only in name, The 538 from 2008-2020 is gone.

Actions by private companies, be they pollsters are generally not on-topic. Poll aggregators fold all the time IIRC.

@timetakesitstoll I was wondering if there is potentially a election-technical reason e.g. if pollsters are not allowed to include non-nominated candidates in their averages.

There's not much regulation in the US on such matters.

They don't appear to have outright folded 'cause they are still posting some blog articles  https://abcnews.go.com/538/5-primaries-watch-arizona-tennessee/story?id=112370118 This wiki sectoin about "cost-cutting" is probably relevant though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FiveThirtyEight#2023_cost-cutting_and_2024_elections

FWTW, although  Nate is no longer with 538, he's also been slow to update https://www.natesilver.net/p/kamala_mode-will-be-activated-tomorrow Interestingly he claims that Harris is less likely to win than Biden [was], despite the national polls https://www.natesilver.net/p/harris-trump-electoral-college

@timetakesitstoll Where does Nate claim she's less likely?  Everything I've seen on his blog has said she's doing better than Biden was.

@JamesK I agree that 538 is basically dead and gone, with the exception of the podcast (which has still been decent, at least as of a month or two ago).  Of course, for anyone who doesn't listen to podcasts, that doesn't help.

@Bobson: "we show Harris as having a slightly wider popular vote-Electoral College gap than Biden had in his version of the forecast." The details are for payers only though. He seems to give Harris higher [overall] odds than Biden though, so possibly I've read too much into that one sentence. On another page (updated today, i.e. one day later than other page I took that quote from) he gives Harris 43% chance of winning the presidency vs Biden's 27%.

The podcast does have an answer to this question, so it is now answerable.  Apparently, they haven't restarted the model for the same reason that Trump won't agree to debate Harris - she's not locked in as the nominee yet, since none of the convention delegates are bound to vote for her (unlike they would have been for Biden).  Since there is the possibility that she won't be nominated, they aren't going to start the model up again until she is.  If the question gets reopened, I can add a link and direct quote.

@Bobson they did, however, post the polling averages including Harris yesterday.

The might have been convinced by the 'virtual roll call' in which Harris achieved the necessary delegate majority. https://www.latimes.com/politics/story/2024-08-02/the-virtual-roll-call-to-nominate-kamala-harris-is-underway-this-is-how-it-will-work
